# Determine supported HTTP version by the web server

Tags: http

Is there a way to check whether a web server supports HTTP 1.0 or 1.1? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could issue a:

```
 curl --head www.test.com
```

that will print out the HTTP version in the first line of the output...

e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 28925
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jun 2009 16:08:04 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "a41944978f6c91:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2009 06:13:25 GMT
```

Comment: Assuming that curl is installed on that platform. OR, he could call the web server with ANY component that can do HTTP, and retrieve the version number from there.

Comment: In case anyone is struggling while running the command above in Git Bash for Windows, the header (see bold part) is printed at the end of this long line (it seems there is a missing newline character there)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0**HTTP/1.1 302 Found**

Comment: No, this is wrong. It will only show versions up to the versions that your client (you) are using. For example, depending from where you are initiating the command from, you can get for example HTTP 1.1 or HTTP/2 - so be careful with this option to determine the maximum http version of the version.

Comment: I have discovered that if you use HTTPS and add the `-v` parameter that you get a list of the supported protocols ie.: `* ALPN, offering h2    * ALPN, offering http/1.1`

Answer (score 10):

In Google Chrome you can see protocol of each requests like this

1. open developers tools with F12
2. go to **Network Tab**
3. right click any where in column headers (like Name in the picture) and from the context menu select **Protocol** to be displayed as a new column
4. then you will see  values like h2 (HTTP 2) or http/1.1  entry like the following picture in **Protocol** column

[image]

Comment: For clearance, what the author means by right click is right-clicking the Name, Status, etc. columns and not the Network Tab

Answer (score 3):

This should work on any platform that includes a telnet client:

```
telnet <host> 80
```

Then you have to type one of the following blind:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
```

or
    GET /

and hit enter twice.

The first line returned should output the HTTP version supported:

```
telnet www.stackoverflow.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 315
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2009 15:15:15 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the release notes or the documentation of the webserver to check that. For example Apache Tomcat documentation tells it supports `HTTP 1.1`

Which webserver are you looking for?

Also are you asking if this can be checked programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

In Google Chrome and Brave, you can easily use the Developer tools (F12 or `Command + Option + I`). Open the Network tab, find the request, click the Header tab, scroll down to "Response Headers", and click `view source`. It should show the HTTP version in the first line.

In the screenshot below, the server is using HTTP/1.1, as you can see: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. If that is missing, it's HTTP/2, since there is no readable source, it's in binary instead.

[image: Network tab screenshot of a Google Chrome browser]

Comment: I don't see the 'view source' option. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I tried it on google.com and the button was missing. However, on `news.ycombinator.com`, the "view source" button was present. If it's missing, it's HTTP/2, reason explained on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867107

Answer (score 1):

$curl --head https://url:port -k

You get result something like...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
blah....blah.
blah...blah..

$
So first line shows version it supports..

Comment: How does this provide any further information than the accepted answer to this question?

Comment: just to clarify the syntax to use and get through it quickly.

Comment: Essentially, you added only the last line and otherwise more or less copied the other solution without giving proper attribution. You should at least give attribution to Jon!

Comment: i had similar req. as i personally executed the above commands for my project.don't comment so blunt.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use `netcat` so that you don't have to type it blindly as in `telnet`.

```
user@linux:~$ nc www.stackoverflow.com 80
HEAD / HTTP

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0


user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two additional methods that can be used to determine the version of HTTP supported by a web server:

### `Alt-Svc` header

Upon a request to the server, the server may return a `Alt-Svc` header which can specify which versions of HTTP are supported. This information can be used by the browser to determine an upgrade from HTTP/2 to HTTP/3 is possible. For example, when I visit `www.google.com`, the first request is a HTTP/2 request and contains the following `Alt-Svc` header:

```
alt-svc: h3=':443'; ma=2592000,h3-29=':443'; ma=2592000
```

Here, the `h3` means HTTP/3. After this response is received, my browser starts to issue HTTP/3 requests instead of HTTP/2.

[image]

### `ALPN` parameter of the `SVCB` and `HTTPS` DNS resource records (RR)

Since [November 2023](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9460) there is a new mechanism for specifying which version of HTTP is supported by a server: the application-level protocol negotiation (ALPN) parameter of the `SVCB` and `HTTPS` DNS RR.

Using a tool like `dig`, you can query this header directly to view it's definition:

```
dig www.google.com HTTPS
```

which responds with:

```
www.google.com.     10061   IN  HTTPS   1 . alpn="h2,h3"
```

Here you can see the ALPN value is `h2` for HTTP/2 and `h3` for HTTP/3.