# How does "view source" in response headers go missing for certain sites

Tags: google-chrome, firebug, developer-tools

In developer tools in Chrome, sometimes the "view source" in response headers missing for certain sites? Any ideas why? Take yahoo.com site for example.

This site is just fine.

[image]

But yahoo is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because yahoo.com upgraded to using HTTP/2.

HTTP/2 is a **binary** protocol. How to display it? As HEX? Or just download the response? It won't make much sense to show the raw binary as text. Probably that's why Chrome removed the 'view source' option for HTTP/2 responses.

Comment: Is there no way to download the response?

Comment: @Hiccup You can export the request as a HAR file.

Comment: @buckley I mean the response header, in binary form.

Comment: @Ivan Nikolchov Is there any methods to see raw headers. I can inspect raw headers in lower chrome version in http2. Sometimes i need to copy the requests headers to do some crawl function . Can't  view source make copy infos harder. It's note correct format

Answer (score 1):

Try firefox to access yahoo.com. It will show raw headers.

[image: Sample pic: access yahoo.com with firefox]